# grep forward slash to forward slash

Tags: grep

I have HTML files that contain a lot of URLs.
I try to grep only the forward slash to end with forward slash like:

```
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/123456/"
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/993455/xxx/ff/3e/"
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/74939300/"
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/9584443/"
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/9583832/cdf/dr/wwe/"
```

my expected results are:

```
/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/123456/
/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/74939300/
/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/9584443/
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
grep -P -o '/.*?/[0-9]+/'
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's|["]*(/.*?)(/[0-9]+/).*|\1\2|'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/123456/"
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/993455/xxx/ff/3e/"
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/74939300/"
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/9584443/"
"/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/9583832/cdf/dr/wwe/"
```

```
grep -Po '"\K[^"]+?/\d+/(?=")' file.txt
/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/123456/
/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/74939300/
/index.php/pub/xx/en/details/9584443/
```

**Explanation:**

```
-Po             # Perl regex, only the matched string
"               # a double quote
\K              # forget it
[^"]+?          # 1 or more non double quote, not greedy
/               # a slash
\d+             # 1 or more digits
/               # a slash
(?=")           # positive lookahead, make sure we have a double quote after
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to grep “forward slash to forward slash”. 
I guess that means that you want to get the first slash
*through* the last slash, leaving out any character(s)
before the first slash and after the last slash
(which are **`"`** quotes, in your data). 
Without explanation, you show that you want to get
only lines that have exactly six pathname components; i.e., seven slashes.

One command, with a PCRE:

```
grep -Po '(?<=")/([^/]*/){6}(?=")' file.txt
```

Two commands, without PCREs:

```
grep -E '"/([^/]*/){6}"' file.txt | grep -o '/.*/'
```